# ¿Cómo enumerar con letras a través de emmet en sublimetext?

Tags: html, sublimetext3, emmet

Tengo instalado emmet en sublime y quiero saber como numerar automaticamente con letras.Con número se que es así:

```
div*5{caja $}
```

Y yo quiero letras de la **a** a la **z** en vez de números. Me ayudais???? mil gracias